# Finding languages such that $L_1\subset L_2\subset L_3$ where $L_1,L_3\notin$ RE and $L_2\in$ R

Tags: computability, formal-languages, automata, turing-machines

I am struggling to find such languages $L_1$, $L_2$, and $L_3$ such that
$L_1\subset L_2\subset L_3$
where $L_1,L_3\notin$ RE and $L_2\in$ R.

I know they exist, I need help finding them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be some language not in RE. Take

- $L_1 = 0L$.
- $L_2 = 0\Sigma^*$.
- $L_3 = 0\Sigma^* \cup 1L$.